# How do we extract relational and structure data from PDF files contains metadata and relation of controls with their labels

Tags: c#, pdf

Data contains a relation between the label and its  control in Acroform PDF files, gives information about which control is associated with which label

Comment: Which library are you using to access your PDF ?

Comment: And even with that information your question remains unclear because (as far as the PDF standard is concerned) there does not need to be any specific relation of label and field other than that they are positioned fairly near to each other. Essentially ask yourself how you recognize which labels and fields are associated when looking at a form and try to put that in code.